# Sage Line 50 ODBC issues with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc, sage-line-50

I'm trying to connect to Sage Line 50 ODBC (uk). This works fine if I use Python 2.7 when I change over to 3.7 it will not work bringing up the following error.

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] Cannot find all files in data path (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] The driver returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 24.2 (444); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr). (0)")
```

Here is the code which works on 2.7 and fails on 3.7

```
    username= "username"
    password= "password"
    driver = "{Sage Line 50 v24}"
    DSN = "SageLine50v24_64"
    self.conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=driver, DSN=DSN, UID=username, PSW=password)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    print ('Connected to SAGE')
```

I've even used 32 and 64bit versions of Python 3 with no success. I'm at a complete loss as to why it doesn't work. Is there a config in pyodbc I'm missing?

Comment: *(Also asked on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/542).)*

Comment: You would need to configure ODBC. On Linux that means editing `odbc.ini` and possbly `odbcinst.ini` in the right place.

Comment: Turns out you don't need the driver param. Works fine.